# Sum of operators on superposition state

Tags: operators, superposition, quantum-states

I'm a little confused about how a sum of operators acting on a superposition state are worked out.

For instance, the superposition of Fock States (photonic)
$$\vert \psi \rangle = \alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta\vert 1 \rangle$$

(Where $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2=1$). And we want to calculate the expectation value of, say, the quadrature operator $\hat{X}_1 = \frac{\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger}{2}$.

The thing that confuses me here is how the sum $\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger$ acts on $\alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta\vert 1 \rangle$. I know the answer should be $\beta \vert 0 \rangle + \alpha\vert 1 \rangle$, i.e. swaps the amplitudes, but I don't see how to do it explicitly.

\begin{align}
\hat{X}_1\vert\psi\rangle &= (\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger)(\alpha \vert 0 \rangle + \beta\vert 1 \rangle)\\
&=(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger)\alpha \vert 0 \rangle + (\hat{a} + \hat{a}^\dagger)\beta\vert 1 \rangle
\end{align}

I can see how the first part should return $\alpha\vert 1\rangle$, since the annihilation goes to 0 when used on the vacuum state, and then its a simple creation on vacuum. But I don't see how the second part should reduce to $\beta\vert 0\rangle$. Shouldn't there also be a subsequent creation?

Comment: Are you concerned with the expectation value or the state itself?  $\hat{X}_1 |\psi\rangle$ will have a $|2\rangle$ component, but that component won't affect the expectation value $\langle \psi | \hat{X}_1 |\psi\rangle$ since $|\psi\rangle$ has no $|2\rangle$ component.

Comment: Ah, I believe that's where I messed up. I couldn't how the $\vert 2\rangle$ component vanished, but of course it only vanishes in the expectation due to orthogonality; not from the action of $\hat{X}_1$. Thanks.